# how to efficiently merge two arrays of date objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date, lodash

The first array is a master list of date objects containing unique javascript Date objects:

```
[
   {'date': dateobject1, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject2, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject3, 'value': null},
   etc...
]
```

The first array is a much smaller list of date objects containing a subset of the unique javascript Date objects, with the 'value' property always having a number rather than a `null`:

```
[
   {'date': dateobject3, 'value': 3117},
   {'date': dateobject8, 'value': 14},
   etc...
]
```

Keeping in mind the nuances of comparing date objects - https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/538962 - what would be the most efficient way to merge these objects - in an environment where lodash 3.10.1 is available -
 based on matching dates so that the merged array is a list of all dates: matches mean the 'value' becomes the numeric value, and otherwise the `null` 'value' is retained when there is no match?

```
[
   {'date': dateobject1, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject2, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject3, 'value': 3117},
   {'date': dateobject4, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject5, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject6, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject7, 'value': null},
   {'date': dateobject8, 'value': 14},
   etc...
]
```

Comment: is each list already sorted ?

Comment: Are there any duplicates? Either multiple references to the same Date object, or unique Dates with the same time value?

Comment: @TimCodes - yes; each list is already sorted.

Comment: @RobG - the date objects in the master list are unique.

Comment: @mg1075— `new Date(2017,0,1)` and `new Date(2017,0,1)`  create two unique Date objects, but they have the same time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in *Array.prototype.map* to create a new array from the existing array values.

Where you say:

> The first array is a much smaller list of date objects containing a subset of the unique javascript Date objects

I'm assuming that *dateobject3* is the same object in both arrays, not two different objects for the same date.

The following creates an index for the *values* array to save iterating over *values* for each member of *data*. It won't make a noticeable difference for small data sets (say less than 100 values), but will for larger ones (say more than a few hundred or a thousand).

```js
var d0 = new Date(2017,1,1),
    d1 = new Date(2017,1,2),
    d2 = new Date(2017,1,3);

var data = [
   {'date': d0, 'value': null},
   {'date': d1, 'value': null},
   {'date': d2, 'value': null}
];

var values = [
   {'date': d1, 'value': 3117},
];

// Generate a values index, saves searching
// through values for each member of data
var indexes = values.map(obj => obj.date);
// Generate merged array
var merged = data.map(obj => {
  var index = indexes.indexOf(obj.date); 
  return {date: obj.date, value: index > -1? values[index].value : obj.value};
});

console.log(merged)
```

If on the other hand the dates are different objects but with the same time value, then you need to compare the time value instead. A simple way to get the time value is to use unary `+`, it just saves typing over *getValue* or *getTime*:

```js
var data = [
   {'date': new Date(2017,1,1), 'value': null},
   {'date': new Date(2017,1,2), 'value': null},
   {'date': new Date(2017,1,3), 'value': null}
];

var values = [
   {'date': new Date(2017,1,2), 'value': 3117},
];

// Generate a values index using the date time value
// saves searching through values for each member of data
var indexes = values.map(obj => +obj.date);
// Generate merged array
var merged = data.map(obj => {
  var index = indexes.indexOf(+obj.date); 
  return {date: obj.date, value: index > -1? values[index].value : obj.value};
});

console.log(merged)
```

If each date will only have one match, you can optimise further by removing matched indexes when they're matched so subsequent lookups are (possibly imperceptibly) faster.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. I would use the `reduce` method on the master list to see if the other list contains a matching date - if so merge the two objects and push to the new array, if not just push the object from the master list. Mind you this is using es6 - if es6 is not available to you in the environment you are using lodash has a `reduce` and `assign` method

```
const masterList = [/* ... */];
const otherArray = [/* ... */];

const mergedArray = masterList.reduce((a, b) => {
  const match = otherArray.filter(({ date }) => date.getTime() === b.date.getTime());
  if(match) {
    a.push(Object.assign(b, match));
  } else {
    a.push(b);
  }

  return a;
}, []);
```

Comment: This mutates the members of *masterList* at `Object.assign(b, match)`, so  on completion *mergedArray* is a set of references to the elements in the mutated *masterList*. So you might as well use *forEach* instead of *reduce* and not bother with *mergedArray*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Think using a hashset would be one of the quicker ways
https://codepen.io/TimCodes/pen/brQvbo?editors=0012

```
var masterListArr = [ { 'date' : new Date(), 'value' : 2 } , {'date' : new Date(2013, 13, 1), 'value' : 0}]
var secondListArr = [ { 'date' : new Date(), 'value' : null } , {'date' : new Date(2014, 13, 1), 'value' : null}]

var masterListHash = masterListArr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[cur['date'].getTime()] = cur['value'] ;
  return acc;
}, {});


var mergedList = secondListArr.map(dateObj => {
   var dateKey = dateObj.date.getTime()
   if(masterListHash.hasOwnProperty(dateKey)){
        dateObj.value = masterListHash[dateKey]
   }
   return dateObj
})
```

Comment: Using the time value as the key raises the question of duplicate dates. Also, you're building a plain object, not a hash. The distinction may be subtle, but ECMAScript may get real hashes in the future (e.g. it recently acquired Map and Set objects). You could create a Map and use the Date object itself as the key (if the dates in the two arrays are the same object). Dunno if that's what the OP meant by "*…containing a subset of the unique javascript Date objects*" though.